# How to melt data in a data frame with a two-row header in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, header, reshape, melt

```
data <- data.frame(Q1_1 = c("abc",1,2,3,4),
                   Q1_2 = c("def",2,3,6,2),
                   Q2_1 = c("ghi",4,5,3,1),
                   Q2_2 = c("jkl",6,3,8,4),
                   ID = c("ID", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"),
                   Order = c("Order", "zz", "ss", "tt", "qq"))
```

The above resembles my data frame in terms of its layout, which should look like the one below. The actual data are saved as in a CSV file, once you read it into R with read.csv(), it would create a data frame like this.

```
  Q1_1 Q1_2 Q2_1 Q2_2 ID Order
1  abc  def  ghi  klm ID Order
2    1    2    4    6 AA    zz
3    2    3    5    3 BB    ss
4    3    6    3    8 CC    tt
5    4    2    1    4 DD    qq
```

The trickiest thing about it is that the data file has the first two rows as headers, and once it is read into R, it produces a data frame that presents the secondary header in the first row.

This is what I want to end up seeing. There are the codes that I manually wrote.

```
melted <- data.frame(response = c(1,2,3,4,2,3,6,2,4,5,3,1,6,3,8,4),
                    question_code = c("abc","abc","abc","abc",
                                      "def","def","def","def",
                                      "ghi","ghi","ghi","ghi",
                                      "jkl","jkl","jkl","jkl"),
                    question_number = c("Q1_1","Q1_1","Q1_1","Q1_1",
                                        "Q1_2","Q1_2","Q1_2","Q1_2",
                                        "Q2_1","Q2_1","Q2_1","Q2_1",
                                        "Q2_2","Q2_2","Q2_2","Q2_2"),
                    ID = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD",
                           "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD",
                           "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD",
                           "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"),
                    Order = c("zz", "ss", "tt", "qq",
                              "zz", "ss", "tt", "qq",
                              "zz", "ss", "tt", "qq",
                              "zz", "ss", "tt", "qq"))
```

And it should look like this...

```
   response question_code question_number ID Order
1         1           abc            Q1_1 AA    zz
2         2           abc            Q1_1 BB    ss
3         3           abc            Q1_1 CC    tt
4         4           abc            Q1_1 DD    qq
5         2           def            Q1_2 AA    zz
6         3           def            Q1_2 BB    ss
7         6           def            Q1_2 CC    tt
8         2           def            Q1_2 DD    qq
9         4           ghi            Q2_1 AA    zz
10        5           ghi            Q2_1 BB    ss
11        3           ghi            Q2_1 CC    tt
12        1           ghi            Q2_1 DD    qq
13        6           jkl            Q2_2 AA    zz
14        3           jkl            Q2_2 BB    ss
15        8           jkl            Q2_2 CC    tt
16        4           jkl            Q2_2 DD    qq
```

So basically I want to stack the values ("*response*") into one column while creating four columns as references. Two of the four columns are *question_code and question__name,* which are transposed from the original two-header. The rest two column simply presents *ID* and *Order* (I do not know if the way I explained is understandable, but all the codes are here).

If the data file has only one row as header, I know how to do it with `melt()`, but this two-row header seems to largely complicates the situation.

Comment: If these files are outputs from a survey software like Qualtrics there may be packages (like `qualtRics`) that have nice utility functions to handle data in this format.

Comment: Bit of a longshot, but any chance that this is Qualtrics data? There's aren't too many systems that are crazy enough to give you data in this format.

Comment: If it is Qualtrics data, I'd use `qualtRics`. If it isn't, [this is probably what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63912923/gather-a-dataset-with-multiple-header-rows)

Comment: Yes, the dataset is downloaded from Qualtrics. Thank you guys for mentioning the package, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Q'), ~c(str_c(cur_column(),.[1], sep=':'), .[-1]))) %>%
  set_names(.[1,]) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Q'), values_to = 'response', names_sep = ':', 
               names_to = c("question_number", "question_code"))

# A tibble: 16 × 5
   ID    Order question_number question_code response
   <chr> <chr> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>   
 1 AA    zz    Q1_1            abc           1       
 2 AA    zz    Q1_2            def           2       
 3 AA    zz    Q2_1            ghi           4       
 4 AA    zz    Q2_2            jkl           6       
 5 BB    ss    Q1_1            abc           2       
 6 BB    ss    Q1_2            def           3       
 7 BB    ss    Q2_1            ghi           5       
 8 BB    ss    Q2_2            jkl           3       
 9 CC    tt    Q1_1            abc           3       
10 CC    tt    Q1_2            def           6       
11 CC    tt    Q2_1            ghi           3       
12 CC    tt    Q2_2            jkl           8       
13 DD    qq    Q1_1            abc           4       
14 DD    qq    Q1_2            def           2       
15 DD    qq    Q2_1            ghi           1       
16 DD    qq    Q2_2            jkl           4
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the alternate approach

```r
# get the first row for names
row <- data[1,]

# assign the first row as names of the dataset
names(data) <- ifelse(!names(data) %in% c('ID','Order') ,paste0(names(data),'#',row), names(data))

# remove the first row
data2 <- data[2:nrow(data),]

# transpose the data
data3 <- data2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Q')) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c('question_number','question_code'), sep='#') %>% rename(response=value)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 16 × 5
   ID    Order question_number question_code response
   <chr> <chr> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>   
 1 AA    zz    Q1_1            abc           1       
 2 AA    zz    Q1_2            def           2       
 3 AA    zz    Q2_1            ghi           4       
 4 AA    zz    Q2_2            jkl           6       
 5 BB    ss    Q1_1            abc           2       
 6 BB    ss    Q1_2            def           3       
 7 BB    ss    Q2_1            ghi           5       
 8 BB    ss    Q2_2            jkl           3       
 9 CC    tt    Q1_1            abc           3       
10 CC    tt    Q1_2            def           6       
11 CC    tt    Q2_1            ghi           3       
12 CC    tt    Q2_2            jkl           8       
13 DD    qq    Q1_1            abc           4       
14 DD    qq    Q1_2            def           2       
15 DD    qq    Q2_1            ghi           1       
16 DD    qq    Q2_2            jkl           4
```